# Can a writ of mandamus be filed in any Indian High Court?

Tags: india, rules-of-court, indian-constitutional-law, writ-of-mandamus

I am planning to file a writ of mandamus in an Indian High Court against a Government statutory body. Can it be filed in any High Court or is it necessary to file it in a specific High Court within whose jurisdiction the Government body rests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can a writ of mandamus be filed in any Indian High Court?**

**NO**, Either the respondent or the cause of action has to be in the High Court's jurisdiction. See clauses 1 and 2 of [Article 226](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1712542/) of the Indian Constitution respectively:

> (1) ... every High Court shall have powers, throughout the territories in relation to which it exercise jurisdiction, to issue to ... **any Government within those territories** directions ... including writs in the nature of ... mandamus ...
>
> (2) The power conferred by clause ( 1 ) to issue ... writs to any Government ... may also be exercised by any High Court exercising jurisdiction **in relation to the territories within which the cause of action, wholly or in part, arises** for the exercise of such power, notwithstanding that the seat of such Government ... is not within those territories